# unable to uninstall sqoop installed though CDH5 on an ubuntu machine

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop, cloudera-manager, sqoop2

I uninstalled sqoop from Cloudera Manager, but I still see sqoop version through terminal:

```
chaithu@localhost:~$ sqoop version
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/12/24 18:49:28 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.1
Sqoop 1.4.6-cdh5.13.1
git commit id 
Compiled by  on Thu Nov  9 08:38:43 PST 2017
```

attaching the cloudera manager services running, I din't see any sqoop running.
I want to uninstall/delete sqoop completly.
Can anyone help me?

[image: Cloudera Manager running apps]

Answer (score 1):

The methodology of uninstallation is no different than other packages on the OS.

```
apt-get purge sqoop
```

Also, Cloudera Manager lists Sqoop2 server. Your CLI is for Sqoop1